# React tab is not showing with Chrome's react developer tools on a react-native app

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, react-native

I have installed the `react developer tools` extension in Chrome, and if I look at the list of extensions, it is listed as enabled.  However, on the top menu bar, where I have Elements, Console, Sources etc, there is no React tab. I can open one of my react-native source files and even stop at a breakpoint in it.

In readme of the react developer tools [gihub repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) it states

```
The "React" tab won't show up if React can't communicate with the devtools. When the page loads, the devtools sets a global named __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__, then React communicates with that hook during initialization.

(In React 0.11 and older, it was necessary to expose a global called React for the devtools to function.)

You can test this on the React website or by inspecting Facebook.
```

In my app folder, I am not using react directly, but I am using react-native and the relevant versions are

```
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.21.0
```

If I go to the react-native site, the React tab shows up, so it is probably something to do with my react-native setup. How do I get the React tab to appear when I am inspect my react-native app?

Comment: Are you on a page that has React stuff on it?

Comment: I sometimes get that. Restart chrome or ctrl+f5 does it for me

Comment: In regards to MarkNFI's comment, I am definitely on a page with React code on it. In regard to MattDuFeu's comment, I tried restarting and it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's currently not possible to use the "React" tab in the devtools to inspect app widgets. This is due to a change in how the application scripts are evaluated in the devtools plugin; they are now run inside a Web Worker, and the plugin is unaware of this and so unable to communicate properly with React Native.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#devtools-react-tab-does-not-work

You can try http://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/#debugging__element-inspector as was suggested in issue on github, but I can't get it to work with RN 0.21

Answer (score 0):

I had been using react in web and mobile both and used to debug the react elements in react tab in web but when we go to  react-native the react tab does not appear

Fortunately there is tool called nuclide which enables to debug react-native flawlessly follow the below steps :

Install atom plugin called nuclide

starting with installing nuclide :

> apm install nuclide

2. Restart atom editor if open
3. Go to Nuclide menu in atom -> React -> Toggle Inspector which will show message “Connecting to React” or                 possibly when you have not started react packager then it would say “Waiting to connect”
4. This is optional stpe to flow sometime the nuclide says flow module not found hence you need to install below               atom plugin to make react inspector work with react-native.

> ```
>  npm install --save-dev flow-bin
> ```

Make sure you install this inside your react-native project and start project with :

> react-native run-android

This will make your react-native inspector enable with elements shown on device , Done !

Note :  there are couple of interesting stuff you can do with inspector  (helps a lot for react-native debugging ):

Tap on any of element on UI and the element is poped up in inspector
You can change run-time style similarly how to change css in web